# Find .offset of each element with X class

Tags: jquery, variables, offset

I'd like to know how you can get the .offset of multiple elements with variables, the idea would be something like this:

```
var position = $(this).offset().top;
$(".number").text(position);
```

And that way, every element with the .number class would display its own particular offset, the problem is that this isn't working, it's undefined, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function parameter of [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) method:

```
$(".number").text(function(){
   return $(this).offset().top; // or this.offsetTop (relative to parent node)
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! I'll accept answer as soon as it lets me.